# Open pdf file from a different directory/folder

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am using the version of Excel in Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013.

Using Excel VBA, I would like to launch Adobe Reader XI and open a pdf file located in another folder.

I can successfully open the Adobe Reader file if the Excel file and the Adobe Reader file are in the same folder.  Here’s the code that works:

```
Dim ABCfilename As String
Dim returnAcrobatfile As Variant
ABCfilename = "ABC.pdf"
acrobatFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ABCfilename
returnAcrobatfile = Shell("C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader _
11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe " & acrobatFile, vbNormalFocus)
```

However, I would like to launch Adobe Reader and program it to open a pdf file that is located in a different folder.

My Excel file is in a folder named C:\Customers\Pricing\

My Adobe file is in a folder named Z:\XYZ Company\

How should I modify the line of code that starts with returnAcrobatfile so that it opens a pdf file located in Z:\XYZ Company ?

Comment: Change `ThisWorkbook.Path` to the correct path.

Comment: You should change the line of code that starts with acrobatFile to the correct path.

Comment: Thanks Comintern & Kevin.  It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

see code below.

```
Sub PDF_Picker()

Dim Acrobatfile         As String

Acrobatfile = GetFile
Runit (Acrobatfile)

End Sub

Sub Runit(FileName As String)
   Dim Shex As Object
   Dim tgtfile As String
   Set Shex = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   tgtfile = FileName
   Shex.Open (tgtfile)
End Sub

Function GetFile()

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select PDF Files"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Adobe PDF Files", "*.pdf"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        If .Show = True Then
            GetFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            GetFile = False
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

- If your client has Acrobat installed in a different location from the path you hardcoded your solution will fail. I adapted it to make it more robust and use default application choice for PDF. BTW if you drop/delete the filter in the function GetFile: (`.Filters.Add "Adobe PDF Files", "*.pdf"`)
  you can USE THIS TO OPEN ANY FILE even mp3s as I've just tested.
- Credit to tigeravatar, I adapted his function for your purposes from this post:
  [Importing folder to Excel (FileDialogFolderPicker) using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136528/importing-folder-to-excel-filedialogfolderpicker-using-vba)
- Credit to user1302114 adapted RunIt Sub from this post: [How can Excel VBA open file using default application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921168/how-can-excel-vba-open-file-using-default-application)

Comment: Thanks so much gokool108.  I'll try your method too.